# How to use an elasticsearch form from a home page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, elasticsearch, search

I have an application set up with articles, a home page, and a search function. I am using elasticsearch for my search functionality. I haven't been able to come up with a way to use the search form on my home page to redirect to the query results. I feel like this should be simple, but I'm just missing it.

Note: Elasticsearch works, just within it's own view folder. I simply want the search form on my home page to operate the same way and take me to a "results" page that shows a list of queried articles.

My search controller:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
    if params[:q].nil?
      @articles = []
    else
      @articles = Article.search params[:q]
    end
  end
end
```

My search view:

```
<h1>Articles Search</h1>

<%= form_for search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label "Search for" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<ul>
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <li>
      <h3>
        <%= link_to article.title, controller: "articles", action: "show", id: article._id%>
      </h3>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The search form on my home page:

```
<div class="search">
  <%= form_for search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], placeholder: "Search..."%>
    <%= submit_tag "Go", name: nil %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My search route:

```
get 'search', to: 'search#search'
```

Comment: can you specify what happens when you run the form on home page, it gives you an error, doesn't search, please add more info about what is happening

Comment: It simply does nothing. The url reflects that a query has been run, but it does not redirect to a new page of results. Even though it's not throwing an error, I'm still having issues with the general process.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the submit with a nil name, can you remove that part and test it